# Difference between Parameter vs. Tensor in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I would like to know the difference between PyTorch Parameter and Tensor?

The existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935345/understanding-torch-nn-parameter/51027227#51027227) is for the old PyTorch where variables are being used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the whole idea of the `Parameter` class (attached) in a single image.

[image]

Since it is sub-classed from `Tensor` it is a Tensor.

But there is a trick. Parameters that are inside of a module are added to the list of Module parameters. If `m` is your module `m.parameters()` will hold your parameter.

Here is the example:

```
class M(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(2, 2))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(2))

    def forward(self, x):
        return x @ self.weights + self.bias

m=M()
m.parameters()
list(m.parameters())

---

[Parameter containing:
 tensor([[ 0.5527,  0.7096],
         [-0.2345, -1.2346]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
 tensor([0., 0.], requires_grad=True)]
```

You see how the parameters will show what we defined.
And if we just add a tensor inside a class, like `self.t = Tensor`, it will not show in the parameters list. That is literally it. Nothing fancy.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference.

Comment: Added a little example, you can improve the example by adding a Tensor as class attribute and check yourself the difference.

Comment: It would have been great if you could add their difference from a use case perspective. When one should use tensors and when one should use parameters.

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @prosti's answer, a `nn.Module` class, doesn't always explicitly knows what Tensor objects it should optimize for. If you go through this simple commented piece of code, it could clarify it further.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

# Simple Objective : Learn a function that maps [1,1] -> [0,0]
x = torch.ones(2)  # input tensor
y = torch.zeros(2)  # expected output

# Model 1 
class M1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(2, 2))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(2))

    def forward(self, x):
        return x @ self.weights + self.bias

# Model 2
class M2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # though the Tensor Objects below can undergo backprop and minimize some loss
        # our model class doesn't know, it should use these tensors during optimization
        self.weights = torch.randn(2,2).requires_grad_(True)
        self.bias = torch.zeros(2).requires_grad_(True)

    def forward(self, x):
        return x @ self.weights + self.bias


m1=M1()
m2 = M2()

# Bunch of parameters get printed
print('Model 1 params : ')
print(list(m1.parameters()))

# This is empty, meaning, there is no parameter for model to optimize
# In the forward pass, model just knows to use these 
# `weight` and `bias` tensor to do some operations over the input. 
# But model doesn't know, it should optimize over those `weight` and `bias` tensors objects
print('Model 2 params : ')
print(list(m2.parameters()))


# Initialize the loss function
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')

## ===== Training ===== ##

# Trainer
def train_loop(model, loss_fn=loss_fn):
    # Simple optimizer
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

    for i in range(5):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f"loss > {loss.item()}")

# ====== Train Model 1 ====== #
# loss will keep on decreasing, as model_1 finds better weights for 
train_loop( m1 )

# ====== Trying to Train Model 2 ====== #
# Code breaks, at this line : optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
# Reason being, that there is no any parameters to optimize for. 
train_loop( m2 )
```

For further clarification, check out this short blog implementing pytorch's `nn.Linear` module.