# How to declare a scalar as a parameter in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to pytorch. I want to know how to declare a scalar as a parameter. I am wondering what's the difference between the following two ways?

```
x = torch.randn(1,1, requires_grad=True)
```

and

```
tensor = torch.randn(1,1)
x = Variable(tensor, requires_grad=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the pytorch official documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated),

The `Variable` API has been deprecated: Variables are no longer necessary to use autograd with tensors. `Autograd` automatically supports Tensors with `requires_grad` set to `True`.

- Variable(tensor) and Variable(tensor, requires_grad) still work as expected, but they return Tensors instead of Variables.
- var.data is the same thing as tensor.data.
- Methods such as var.backward(), var.detach(), var.register_hook() now work on tensors with the same method names.

In addition, one can now create tensors with `requires_grad=True` using factory methods such as `torch.randn()`, `torch.zeros()`, `torch.ones()`, and others like the following:

```
autograd_tensor = torch.randn((2, 3, 4), requires_grad=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Variable` is deprecated, if you want to declare a new parameter, 
you should use `torch.nn.Parameter()`. 
You may use this simply like this :

```
some_weights = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.rand(3, 2))
bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(2))
```

You may also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935345/understanding-torch-nn-parameter), which does a good job on how to use `nn.Parameter()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask another question? I want to create a custom filter for my CNN. This filter has 20 channels and kernel size 5*5, each position of the kernel is a function of two parameters. So I declare these two parameters using torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True) and then write a function to generate the kernel with these two parameters as arguments. I initialize the filter using torch.zeros(20, 5, 5) and then assign kernel value to each of the 20 channels. Is this the correct way to do it? I worry about the automatic gradient calculation.

Comment: Please post a new question concerning that. Also provide a pseudo code or the actual code that you wrote so everything is more clear.