# Very simple optim.SGD training loop not working as expected - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, loss-function, autograd

I've been reading through the PyTorch documentation and I've been trying to figure out MSELoss and autograd. I tried creating a very simple training loop that takes two random tensors and updates the values in each tensor so that the sum all values in `tensor1` plus the sum of all values in `tensor2` add up to some target number. In my example I used 100. Here is how I implemented this:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import torch.optim as optim

loss = nn.MSELoss()
tensor1 = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
tensor2 = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target_sum = torch.FloatTensor(torch.Tensor([100]))
optimizer = optim.SGD([nn.Parameter(tensor1), nn.Parameter(tensor2)], lr=1e-4)
print(str(tensor1.sum().item()) + str(tensor2.sum().item()))
for i in range(100):
    pred = tensor1.sum() + tensor2.sum()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss(pred, target_sum).backward
    optimizer.step()
print(str(tensor1.sum().item()) + str(tensor2.sum().item()))
```

The sums of the tensors before the training loop and after the training loop are the same, but I should be seeing an increase in the sum and have it approach 100. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I think it  might have something to do with my optimizer as the training loop is almost straight out of the documentation example. I'm new to PyTorch and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use abs(pred - target_sum) to calculate `loss` since `pred` and `target_sum` are scalars. Also, remove `nn.Parameter()` wrapper in optim definition.
Here is what I did.

```
In [22]: import torch.nn as nn 
    ...: import torch 
    ...: import torch.optim as optim 
    ...:  
    ...: tensor1 = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True) 
    ...: tensor2 = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True) 
    ...: target_sum = 100 
    ...: optimizer = optim.SGD([tensor1, tensor2], lr=1e-2) 
    ...: print(tensor1.sum().item() + tensor2.sum().item()) 
    ...: for i in range(1000): 
    ...:     pred = tensor1.sum() + tensor2.sum() 
    ...:     optimizer.zero_grad() 
    ...:     loss = abs((pred-target_sum)) 
    ...:     loss.backward() 
    ...:     optimizer.step() 
    ...: print(tensor1.sum().item()+ tensor2.sum().item())
```

This results before and after the loop are as follows

```
-0.777163028717041
100.02290725708008
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I even tried increasing the number of iterations to 1,000,000 and the sums still stayed the same after training.

Comment: Wait, if you just have `pred` and `target_sum` as scalar values, why are you using MSELoss(), you simply do  `loss = abs(pred, target_sum)` and do `loss.backward()`, no? MSELoss(0 actually does batch processing you need to provide it tensors with first dimension being the batch.

Comment: Okay, I got it now, remove nn.Parameter() wrapper around tensor1 and tensor2 in optim definition and it will work.

Comment: That worked! Why does adding nn.Parameter() around the tensors make the tensors fail to update during training?

Comment: I have to check that, I will surely let you know once I get the concrete answer. But it's just it didn't feel right to me. This kind of intuition gets developed when you actively do something. But I will surely get back to you soon. :)

Comment: Read this once, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935345/understanding-torch-nn-parameter, this will give you an understanding of what nn.Parameter() are used for. For these reasons, I felt that nn.Parameter(0 doesn't make any sense here, but I am still thinking why wrapping around the tensor didn't lead to the update.