# Pytorch DataParallel doesn't work when the model contain tensor operation

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

If my model contains only `nn.Module` layers such as `nn.Linear`, nn.DataParallel works fine.

```
x = torch.randn(100,10)

class normal_model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(normal_model, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(10,1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x)

model = normal_model()
model = nn.DataParallel(model.to('cuda:0'))
model(x)
```

However, when my model contains a tensor operation such as the following

```
class custom_model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(custom_model, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(10,5)
        self.weight = torch.ones(5,1, device='cuda:0')
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x) @ self.weight

model = custom_model()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model.to('cuda:0'))
model(x)
```

It gives me the following error

> RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1. Original
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py",
>   line 60, in _worker
>       output = module(*input, **kwargs)   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
>   line 541, in **call**
>       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "", line 7, in forward
>       return self.layer(x) @ self.weight RuntimeError: arguments are located on different GPUs at
>   /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:277

How to avoid this error when we have some tensor operations in our model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with `DataParallel`, but I think it might be because your tensor is not part of the model parameters. You can do this by writing:

`torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5,1))`

Note that you don't have to move it to the gpu when initializing, because now when you call `model.to('cuda:0')` this is done automatically.

I can imagine that `DataParallel` uses the model parameters to move them to the appropriate gpu.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935345/understanding-torch-nn-parameter) for more on the difference between a torch tensor and `torch.nn.Parameter`.

If you don't want the tensor values to be updated by backpropagation during training, you can add `requires_grad=False`.

Another way that might work is to override the `to` method, and initialize the tensor in the forward pass:

```py
class custom_model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(custom_model, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(10,5)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x) @ torch.ones(5,1, device=self.device)
    def to(self, device: str):
        new_self = super(custom_model, self).to(device)
        new_self.device = device
        return new_self
```

or something like this:

```py
class custom_model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device:str):
        super(custom_model, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(10,5)
        self.weight = torch.ones(5,1, device=device)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layer(x) @ self.weight
    def to(self, device: str):
        new_self = super(custom_model, self).to(device)
        new_self.device = device
        new_self.weight = torch.ones(5,1, device=device)
        return new_self
```

Comment: If I use `torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5,1))`, the gradient for this tensor will be recorded, and it will be updated during gradient descent, is it? Using `torch.nn.Parameter()` indeed works, but I don't want it to be trainable.

Comment: Cna someone suggest how to make this non trainable so it doesnt train the ones wrapped with nn.Prameter?

Comment: Just set its `.requires_grad` property to `False.`

Comment: It seems like the class is moved into its own module; Now: `torch.nn.parameter.Parameter`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from @Elgar de Groot since OP also wanted to freeze that layer. To do so you can still use torch.nn.Parameter but then you explicitly set requires_grad to false like this:

```
self.layer = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(5,1))
self.layer.requires_grad = False
```